# emacs interactive function with optional numeric prefix

Tags: emacs, lisp, prefix, option-type

How do I specify a function which has optional numeric prefix, if not, it prompts for a number?  basically how goto-line behaves?

```
(defun my-function(&optional  n)
  ; I have tried
  (interactive "N") ; reads string, no prompt
  (interactive "p") ; defaults to one
  (interactive (if (not n) (read-number "N: "))) ; runtime error
```

so how do I make work?
thanks

Comment: FWIW, if you want a prompt for "N", just add the prompt text after the N; `(interactive "NType a number: ")`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at how `'goto-line` is defined (`M-x find-function goto-line RET`).

```
(defun my-function (n)
  "Example function taking a prefix arg, or reading a number if no prefix arg"
  (interactive
   (if (and current-prefix-arg (not (consp current-prefix-arg)))
       (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))
     (list (read-number "N: ")))))
```